# Is there a way to force the use of the same physical CPU while allocating cores to a pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I was wondering if it was possible to force Kubernetes to allocate the cores from the same CPU while spinning up a POD. What I would like Kubernetes to do is, as new PODs are created, the cores allocated to them should come from -let's say- CPU1 as long as there are cores still available on it. CPU2's, CPU3's, etc. cores should not be used in the newly initiated pod. I would like my PODs to have cores allocated from a single CPU as long as it is possible.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Also, is there a way to see from which physical CPUs the cores(cpu) of a POD is coming from?

Thanks a lot.

**Edit: Let me explain why I want to do this.**

We are running a Spark cluster on Kubernetes. The lead of system/linux administration team warned us about the concept of [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access). He told us that we could improve the performance of our executor pods if we were to allocate the cores from the same physical CPU. That is why I started digging into this.

I found this [Kubernetes CPU Manager](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/24/feature-highlight-cpu-manager/). The documentation says:

> CPU Manager allocates CPUs in a topological order on a best-effort
> basis. If a whole socket is free, the CPU Manager will exclusively
> allocate the CPUs from the free socket to the workload. This boosts
> the performance of the workload by avoiding any cross-socket traffic.

[image]

Also on the same page:

> Allocate all the logical CPUs (hyperthreads) from the same physical
> CPU core if available and the container requests an entire core worth
> of CPUs.

[image]

So now I am starting to think maybe what I need is to *enable the static policy for the CPU manager* to get what I want.

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't really have "CPU" as a concept.  Why do you need such specific control over not just pod placement but process scheduling on individual nodes?

Comment: Hello @DavidMaze. Thanks for the comment. I am editing the question for more info.

Comment: @honor, please note that the kubernetes cpu manager is currently a beta [feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/). It is not yet suited for production environments.

Comment: @PiotrMalec thanks for the heads up!